# How can i find whether the string starts with 's','r','p' in java

Tags: java, regex, apache-commons

Example: This is my string,

```
String sample = "s5656";
```

If the first character of the string contains 's' or 'p' or 'r' means i should remove the character,Otherwise i have to 
return the original string.

Is there any optimized way to do that like "regex" or "StringUtils" in apache common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to add 3rd party `jar` for this kind of simple requirement? You can try as follows

```
String sample = "s5656";
if(sample.startsWith("s")||sample.startsWith("r")||sample.startsWith("p")){
  // do necessary 
}else{
  // do necessary 
}
```

[String#startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Java Doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: I have the jar in my application so we can consume that if it is better than our code.Because  i have a concern regarding nullPointerException so that is also the reason i opt for 3rd party library.But i will accept your solution.

Answer (score 4):

A simple regex could solve your problem :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "s5656s";
    System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("^[spr]", "")); // a String which begins with s,p or r
}
```

O/P:

```
5656s
```

PS: regex here leads to *smaller/simpler* but *inefficient* code. Use *Ruchira's* answer for a rather *long* but efficient code. :)

Comment: System.out.println("indexOf::"+StringUtils.startsWithAny(sample ,new String[] {"s", "r", "p"}));
what about this which one is best??

Comment: @VelNaga -  Yes. You could also use `string.startsWith()`. I was just showing one way. There are multiple ways.

Comment: @TheLostMind why do you thing regex is ineffeicent here.It doesnt even scan the strings.just the starting 1 character ?

Comment: @vks - In Java, using regex will eventually lead to a call to a *Synchronized* method - `Pattern.matcher().' That doesn't happen with 'charAt(0)` or `startsWith()`

Comment: @TheLostMind mmm thanx 4 the info :)

Comment: Seems like OP is having fun.accepting some,downvoting some,upvoting some :P

Comment: @vks - Ya. This is a funny place :P

Answer (score 0):

```
^(s|p|r)
```

Try this.Use `yourString.replaceAll() / replaceFirst()` with `empty string`.Use `m`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/49

Comment: There is no such thing as `g` flag in Java, and use character class instead of alternative for single character.

Answer (score 0):

I should go for `replaceAll` function with multiline modifier `(?m)`.

```
String s = "s5656s\n" +
              "r878dsjhj\n" +
              "fshghg";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^[spr]", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
5656s
878dsjhj
fshghg
```

Comment: This depends on how the data is read. If it is read line by line, it is unlikely that `(?m)` is needed.

Comment: there maybe some possibilities of new line characters would be present in the input string..